# jQuery hoverintent creating and removing element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a script that animates my menu ul element on hover. It also creates a background element for the ul. I have made this script:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    $(".main-navigation ul:first > li").hoverIntent({
        sensitivity: 1,
    interval: 100,
    timeout: 400,
    over: function() {
        if ($(this).children().length > 1) {
        $(this).parent().prepend('<div class="sub-nav" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 250px; display: block; opacity: 1;"></div>');
                $(this).children("ul").css({
            "display" : "block",
            "left" : "250px",
            }).stop().animate({
                top: '-50px',
                opacity: 1,
                }, 500)
                }},
    out: function() { 
    $(".sub-nav").remove();
    $(this).children("ul").stop().animate({
                 "top" : "-500px",
                 "opacity": 0,
                    }, 500).css({
                    "display" : "none",
                    })

            }
        })
    });
```

It works fine, but the problem occurs once I select another menu that is below that one. So, I have two menus with sub-menus. If I select separetly each one of them everything works fine, but if I select first one and then move to the other one the background elements (.sub-nav) doesn't appear.

What am I missing?

JS FIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/r8vx07ae/10/ (try moving your mouse from menu item#2 to menu-item#3)

Comment: It's only the first ul not the first li. THe > selector means it selects onyl li's which parent is ul. It can go without it as well since the html structure doesn't have li's outside of ul's. But I tried without it. Still the same issue.

Comment: @Persijn. Yes. But this one is specific because it has a background that cover the entire screen height.

Comment: I'll tell you before other people come: the html would help and a jsfiddle code snippet that reproduces it would be necessary to fully help you out.

Comment: @Persijin. I made the jsfiddle but it doesn't seem to work for some reason. I tried changing the Jquery version and nothing. It like it doesn't register the hoverintent action. http://jsfiddle.net/r8vx07ae/8/

Comment: @Persjin. Yep, I knew it something like that! Thanks. I'll update the original thread when I mess with css a bit to make it look better.

Comment: @Persijn. Updated the thread. As you can see, the problem reproduces here as well. Moving over from Menu item #2 to #3 makes the background div (sub-nav) dissappear, but it's not reappearing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is the right way to do it, but by meddling around I kinda achieved what I wanted. I did the following:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    $(".main-navigation ul:first li").hoverIntent({
        sensitivity: 1,
    interval: 100,
    timeout: 400,
    over: function() {
        if ($(this).children().length > 1) {
        $(this).parent().prepend('<div class="sub-nav" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 250px; display: block; opacity: 1;"></div>');
                $(this).children("ul").css({
            "display" : "block",
            "left" : "250px",
            }).animate({
                top: '-50px',
                opacity: 1,
                }, 500)
                }}
        })

        .mouseleave(function() {
        $(".sub-nav").remove()
        $(this).children("ul").stop().animate({
                 "top" : "-500px",
                 "opacity": 0,
                    }, 500).css({
                    "display" : "none",
                    })

            })
    });
```

This solved my problem. It works just like I wanted.

JS Fiddle updated as well: http://jsfiddle.net/r8vx07ae/11/

Before selecting the answer I'd like to wait for anyone to maybe update it with a better more clean solution.

Comment: i could make a solution in pure css if you wanted?

Comment: but i really like that you put effort into answering your own question!

Comment: Oh, trust me, I've put my effort :D Been around this thing for 3 days through multiple solutions. It's maybe two months since I did my first jQuery stuff so I'm still a newbie...

Comment: @Persjin. Hey I was thinking. Could it be that the config for interval:100 and timeout: 400 could be the issue? Maybe different config is required for the out function?

Comment: I just tested. Putting the timeout to 100 works great!